# How to cancel loadTransferable(type:)?

Tags: swift, async-await, task, photospicker

I'd like to implement a timeout for loading images from the PhotosPicker in SwiftUI in case there's no internet connection and the images are not available in full resolution on the device yet, for example.

I used a task group with a parallel timer task for this, but unfortunately it seems, that `loadTransferable(type:)` does not handle cancellation. The image loading task does not finish once the timer task has completed and `group.cancelAll()` was called and thus the `switch` block is not entered at all.

The other way round does work: If I pick an image that is available on the device already the timer task is cancelled and the task group finishes.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround or other approach for this?

```
func loadImage(_ image: PhotosPickerItem, timeout milliseconds: Int) async throws -> UIImage {
    var result: Result<UIImage, Error>!
    
    await withTaskGroup(of: Result<UIImage, Error>.self) { group in
        // Load the image.
        group.addTask {
            do {
                if let imageData = try await image.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                    if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        return .success(image)
                    }
                }
                return .failure(MyError.imageCouldNotBeLoaded(details: "Image transfer or decoding issues."))
            } catch {
                return .failure(MyError.imageCouldNotBeLoaded(details: "Unsupported image format."))
            }
        }
        
        // Activate the timeout timer.
        group.addTask {
            do {
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(milliseconds * 1_000_000))
                return .failure(MyError.imageCouldNotBeLoaded(details: "Timeout occured."))
            } catch is CancellationError {
                return .failure(MyError.loadingCancelled)
            } catch {
                return .failure(error)
            }
        }
        
        // Wait for the first result and stop all (other) tasks.
        if let taskResult = await group.next() {
            result = taskResult
            group.cancelAll()
        }
    }

    switch result {
    case .success(let image):
        return image
    case .failure(let error):
        throw error
    case .none:
        throw MyError.imageCouldNotBeLoaded(details: "Task not executed or cancelled.")
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a potential data race issue. But, you may find a simpler implementation using a throwing task group which returns an image and possibly throws. Anyway, if you think `image.loadTransferable(type: )` does not respect the cancellation request, I would suggest to report this to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Since I suspect a data race issue accessing variable `result`, this implementation will simplify your code and does not have data race issues, see below.

However, this does not fix your issue, if `image.loadTransferable(type:)` does not handle cancellation. A task group needs to wait until all child tasks have been completed.

```
private func loadImage(
    _ image: PhotosPickerItem,
    timeout milliseconds: UInt64
) async throws -> UIImage {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(
        of: UIImage.self,
        returning: UIImage.self
    ) { group in
        // Load the image.
        group.addTask {
            let data = try await self.loadTransferable(photosPickerItem: image)
            guard Task.isCancelled == false,
                    let imageData = data,
                    let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            else {
                throw MyError.imageCouldNotBeLoaded(
                    details: Task.isCancelled ? "cancelled"
                    : data == nil ? "content type not supported" : "image data encoding error"
                )
            }
            return image
        }
        
        // Activate the timeout timer.
        group.addTask {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(milliseconds))
            throw MyError.loadingCancelled
        }
        
        // If a child task throws an error and if it will be propagated from
        // this method out of the body of this function, then all remaining
        // child tasks in that group are implicitly canceled.
        guard let image = try await group.next() else {
            fatalError("can't happen") // `group.next()` either throws or it returns an image.
        }
        return image
    }
}
```